# Provide mp4 video through a c# ashx handler doesn't work on the iphone

Tags: c#, asp.net, html5-video

I'm trying to provide a mp4 file using a ashx handler and it doesn't work on the Iphone. Works in Safari PC though.

I want this to work(ashx):

```
<video width="100%" height="auto" controls=""><source type="video/mp4" src="play.ashx"></source></video>
```

Instead of (mp4):

```
<video width="100%" height="auto" controls=""><source type="video/mp4" src="play.mp4"></source></video>
```

Here is my code:

```
    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        context.Response.ClearContent();
        context.Response.ClearHeaders();

        var length = new System.IO.FileInfo(context.Server.MapPath("~/big_buck_bunny.mp4")).Length;

        context.Response.CacheControl = "Public";
        context.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", length.ToString());

        context.Response.ContentType = "video/mp4";
        context.Response.WriteFile(context.Server.MapPath("~/big_buck_bunny.mp4"));

        context.Response.Flush();
        context.Response.Close();

    }
```

Here is the file if you want to download: http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4

The reason why I have to do this is because client wants to control the access to videos.

Fiddler info(only the  differences):

**Request Iphone:**

```
User-Agent: AppleCoreMedia/1.0.0.9A405 (iPhone; U; CPU OS 5_0_1 like Mac OS X; en_us)
Accept: */*
Range: bytes=0-1
Accept-Encoding: identity
Connection: keep-alive
```

**Request Safari Windows**

```
User-Agent: QuickTime/7.7.1 (qtver=7.7.1;os=Windows NT 6.1Service Pack 1)
Pragma: no-cache
```

**The responses are identical**

Comment: Have you used Fiddler to find out the differences in the calls that iOS Safari makes vs. Windows Safari?

Comment: How are you going to control access?

Comment: @p.campbell I've added some fiddler info to the post. Would you mind telling me what exactly should I look for?

Comment: @s_hewitt there will be session control implemented afterwards. Something like if(string.isNullOrEmpty(context.Session["loggedin"]) {GTFO (get the f. out)

Comment: The error is not related to ASHX: my iPhone can't access the site www.vorwaerts-gmbh.de nor clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de. I always get: server not available.

Comment: @CédricBelin the link is just to download the file. You put it somewhere in your application folder and then you run the script.

Comment: Just for debugging purposes, try to set the UserAgent to iPhone in Safari, by going to tools (I believe). Or, you can check in FireFox and Firebug...

Answer (score 1):

On the Request the iPhone sends a Range header. As I find the Safari browser on the mobile devices from Apple picky your server must respond accordingly.

From the [specs](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) (paragraph 14.35.2) and your fiddler output you have to start with sending only the first two bytes and respond with an 206, after that the player will probably come back with GET's that has additional headers set.

I have no iPhone or iPad lying around so I can't verify if this answer holds...

Answer (score 1):

Goto Settings icon on your phone and from Safari options enable plugins. Also make sure that your video is encoded h264 baseline.